# Global build tools can't be installed as a pre-requisite for setting up hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I'm trying to setup hyperledger fabric in my windows 10 system. While installing the pre-requisites mentioned in the fabric's documentation I couldn't install the global build tools. I tried running the command:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

but the installation gets stuck at:
`successfully installed Python 2.7` and it stops at `rpc connection was closed.Stream was closed.`
I also followed the following youtube tutorial but still facing the same problem. The reference link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BeJ6MSKH9k&t=457s

Comment: How are you executing this command ? By cmd or powershell? And which language are you targetting

Comment: @Harshit I'm using git bash command line, as it is mentioned in the hyperledger fabric's documentation that it is more suitable than windows powershell. Anyways, it worked by just changing the command to npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0. Seems the problem is with the latest version of build tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: It works by changing the command to

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0
```

Seems the problem is with the latest version of build tools. Some compatibility issue.